# Numbers on a Field-effect transistor

Tags: transistors, fet

I'm looking for a transistor and managed to find a number of them online however there is also a number at the top which I don't know what it means.

i.e this is what I found online:
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41Gdb8KKCmS._SX522_.jpg

But the one I already have has a different number than KH10. What is KH10 and does it need to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ICs (except the very small SOT-23 and similar sizes) are marked with a part number and a lot tracking code. On those SO-8 packages, there’s only room for a few characters, so both the part number and lot code are abbreviated. Sometimes the lot code is a date code (week / year), and sometimes the lot tracking code has more detail about both where and when the part was made.

If you check the IC datasheet, it should have a detail drawing that shows which of the markings are the part number and which of the markings are tracking numbers that you can ignore.

Those lot tracking numbers are used by QA if you call customer support about a failed part. (I work as an applications engineer at Analog Devices; legacy Maxim Integrated) The manufacturer can often use that tracking number to determine which manufacturing batch the part came from.

Comment: A good number of SOT-23s have lot numbers or date codes on them too; that's what the one or two sideways characters you sometimes see are.